# Extract the paragraph from a PDF that contain a keyword in google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, text-extraction

I have a google drive containing 12,652 pdf files where I want to extract the paragraph that contain a particular keyword from these files. How can I proceed to extract paragrapgh from this files and save it in a excel?

I tried doing this in Python but it is slow and I proceeded with the following code:-

```
# import packages
import PyPDF2
import re
x=[]
# open the pdf file
def func(i):
  reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(i)

  # get number of pages
  num_pages = len(reader.pages)

  # define key terms
  string = "material weakness"

  # extract text and do the search
  for page in reader.pages:
      text = page.extract_text()
      # print(text)
      res_search = re.search(string, text)
      if res_search:
        print(res_search)
        x.append(i)


i=0
for f in files:
  try:
    # print(f)
    # print(i)
    # i+=1
    func(f)
    if i==12651:
      break
  except:
    pass
```

Comment: Perhaps break this into several problems. First you are only interested in PDF files that contain the phrase of interest. Of the files that do contain the phrase, you want to find each paragraph that contains the phrase (a given file may contain the phrase more than once). Having these, save relevant information. So problems to solve: 1. Find pdf files which contain a given phrase. 2. Define what a "paragraph" is 3. Extract paragraphs containing the phrase 4. Save relevant information.

Comment: Proposed breaking problem down, left detailed comment.